# Associating critical zones using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, line

I am new to ArcGIS. I have 5 layers in ArcGIS Pro. Four of them are about the Zones (named as Zone 1 to Zone 4) and are polygon in shape. Zone 1 is considered as the most critical zone. Zone 2 is considered a critical zone so on and so forth.  The fifth layer is about the conductor which is polyline in shape. The conductor layer is passing through a different zone and has shape length as one of the attributes. Some conductors are located in more than one zones. I am trying to find a zone of those conductors who are located in different zones in such a way that if a small length of those conductors comes in critical zones and large length comes in the less critical zone then still we say that conductor is associated with the critical zone. For example, if a conductor length is 50 meters and 5 meters comes in zone 1 and 45 meters comes in zone 3, we would assign zone 1 to the conductor because zone 1 is more critical than zone 3.

I tried the intersection tool(as shown in the figure)

[image]

but it did not help.

Could anyone guide me?

Comment: Intersect is the right tool, so please [Edit] the question to give details of what you tried.

Comment: Added a picture of what I have tried.